# GTM track videos event

Tags: html, video, google-analytics

I wanted to tag all embedded videos on my page. I searched for the solutions but its giving me either for youtube or html5 videos. It there a way I can track all videos event even facebook?

Comment: There is no "one size fits all" solution that would cover all possible vendors and technologies.

Comment: Thanks.. I have created a separate script for youtube and html5 videos.. but i cannot find anything for facebook. :(